# Python calendar add custom colors

Tags: python

I want to create a calendar using the python module `calendar` with custom colors in some days, like holidays, but I haven't found anything in the documentation about this, so I wonder if there is a way of doing this. Right now I only have the basic calendar output.

```
import calendar
c = calendar.HTMLCalendar(calendar.SUNDAY) 
c.formatmonth(2020,9)
```

Answer (score 1):

The source code for [the `calendar` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/calendar.py) may help you here.

Note that the [`formatday` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/calendar.py#L436-L444) does not get as an argument the month or year---so even by subclassing `HTMLCalendar`, you will not be able to get what you want.

Your best bet is likely to copy the code for `HTMLCalendar`, and customize it to your needs. Make sure to add a comment that the code is derived from the cpython implementation, and is bound by its license terms.